# How to select values from Numpy array based on fuzzy conditions?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Say I have the following array, and I want to only keep the row where the first column value is 39 (±1) and the second column value is -1 (±1):

```
[[39.26783752, -0.84259111],
[24.44051933,  2.33262944],
[28.28138924,  6.79832602],
[37.54968262,  7.43038321]]
```

I know that if I had simpler conditions, I could do it like so:

```py
np.where((next_points_arr[:, 0] > 39) & (next_points_arr[:, 1] < 1))
```

I also know that I can use `math.isclose(39, 39.2, abs_tol = 1)`, but I'm not sure how to combine the two effectively?

The way I'd approach is to create two more columns with booleans which will signify if the condition is true, and then use `np.where()` to find `True` in each column but that doesn't seem smart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check both conditions with [`np.isclose`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html)

```
a = np.array(
    [[39.26783752, -0.84259111],
     [24.44051933,  2.33262944],
     [28.28138924,  6.79832602],
     [37.54968262,  7.43038321]])

a[np.isclose(a, [39, -1], atol=[1.,1.]).all(1)]
```

Out:

```
array([[39.26783752, -0.84259111]])
```